# Power Shell Output filter

Tags: powershell

I'm using the comand Get-AzresourceGroup. The ouput of that command is information about ResourID, Tags, Resource group name etc. of all resource groups in Azure. I want to store in a variable all the names of the resource groups, I do not need the other information. Is there a way I can do that?

Thank you!

[Comand Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkc0a.png)

Comment: Please do not post links to pictures. Instead, please copy and paste the information into your question with code formatting (4 space indent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `Get-AzResourceGroup` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azresourcegroup?view=azps-6.1.0#example-5--show-the-names-of-all-the-resource-groups-in-a-particular-location), you can simply reference only the Resource Group Name :

```
$groups = (Get-AzResourceGroup).ResourceGroupName
```

Or using the CLI, and extracting from the JSON:

```
$group = az group list | ConvertFrom-Json
$group | Select-Object -Property Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try piping the output from `Get-AzResourceGroup` to `Select-Object` and use the `-Property` parameter to specify the property/properties to select.

```
$rgs = Get-AzResourceGroup | Select-Object -Property ResourceGroupName
```

Your will results should look something like this.

```
$rgs

ResourceGroupName
-----------------
ddo-06212021-1
ddo-06212021-2
ddo-06212021-3
cloud-shell-storage-eastus
```

If you're unsure what properties are available to select from the results of `Get-AzResourceGroup`, you can first pipe the output to `Get-Member`, and view the available properties.

```
Get-AzResourceGroup | Get-Member

   TypeName: Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.SdkModels.PSResourceGroup

Name              MemberType Definition
----              ---------- ----------
Equals            Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode       Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType           Method     type GetType()
ToString          Method     string ToString()
Location          Property   string Location {get;set;}
ManagedBy         Property   string ManagedBy {get;set;}
ProvisioningState Property   string ProvisioningState {get;set;}
ResourceGroupName Property   string ResourceGroupName {get;set;}
ResourceId        Property   string ResourceId {get;set;}
Tags              Property   hashtable Tags {get;set;}
TagsTable         Property   string TagsTable {get;}
```

### Links

[Select-Object - learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-5.1)
[Get-Member - learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member?view=powershell-5.1)